# VS Code complaining about indentation when adding multiline comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, indentation, multiline

No idea what is going on here. To reproduce:

This code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 21 11:28:39 2022

@author: roland
"""

# #!/usr/bin/env python3
# # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# """
# Created on Thu Jul 21 11:28:39 2022

# @author: roland
# """

def fun(num):
    """
    BlaBlaBla
    """    
    # Remove events with no picks and change channel labels to picks of S phases          
    print("Number is ", num)

fun(5)
```

This one does not work!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 21 11:28:39 2022

@author: roland
"""

def fun(num):
    """
    BlaBlaBla
    """    
    # Remove events with no picks and change channel labels to picks of S phases          
    print("Number is ", num)

fun(5)
```

Returned error message:  "File `<ipython-input-1-481aed6c0ac5>`, line 4 BlaBlaBla ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Comment: why do you have added the top 7 lines again in comments

Comment: I copy/past the `does not work` and have no problems

Comment: If I remove the 7 commented lines, it does not work, and I get the error message about the indentation. Weirdest VS Code issue ever!

Comment: if I copy/past the top code block and run it from the terminal: **no problem**, you only have a few lines with spaces at the end, do you have a few tabs mixed with spaces in the original file

Comment: use a hex dump/editor to view the true content of the file